# Use TreeNode Class to work with hierarchically structured data without a TreeView

Tags: vb.net, treeview, hierarchy, treenode

I am somehow stuck and can't see the forest for the trees.

**What I want to do:**
I have a large list of data (about 6000 nodes), at the moment pretty simple:

- Unique ID
- Parent
- List of Children
- List item

Currently, this is flat data but I want to create a hierarchy of it, so i can

- search for UniqueID in a specific depth of the tree
- for any ID, list row of parents up to the root
- list all childrens of a single ID
- loop through entries (vertical, horizontal)
- order horizontal items
- List items

**What I tried:**
I started with this code:
[see link](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4633/tree-structures-in-aspnet-and-sql-server/)

```vb
<Serializable> _
Public Class TreeNode
    Private _uniqueID As Integer
    Private _name As String
    Private _parentID As Integer
    Private _depth As Integer
    Private _children As ArrayList
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(name As String, parentID As Integer)
        Me.New(0, name, parentID, -1)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(uniqueID As Integer, name As String, parentID As Integer, depth As Integer)
        _uniqueID = uniqueID
        _name = name
        _parentID = parentID
        _depth = depth
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the unique ID associated with this category
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Once a non-zero ID has been set, it may not be modified.</remarks>
    Public Property UniqueID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _uniqueID
        End Get
        Set
            If _uniqueID = 0 Then
                _uniqueID = value
            Else
                Throw New Exception("The UniqueID property cannot be modified once it has a non-zero value")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Depth() As Integer
        Get
            Return _depth
        End Get
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the label for this node
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The ID of the parent node
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property ParentID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _parentID
        End Get
        Set
            _parentID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the children TreeNode objects for this category
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>In .NET 2.0, this can be modified to use generics, and have type ArrayList&lt;TreeNode></remarks>
    Public Property Children() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return _children
        End Get
        Set
            _children = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I created my tree:

```vb
Public Dendrogram As List(Of TreeNode)
```

.. and added all nodes to it. Super clean, understandable, **but no functions!**

This brought me to [another approach](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/30/tree-node-nodes-descendants-ancestors.aspx) But it is far too complex for my purposes.

.. then I was wondering: why not use the TreeNode Class from MS? But I don't want to use the TreeView associated with it. There is [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23949/Building-Trees-from-Lists-in-NET) example, but it is in C and I can't seem to apply it in VBNet (got stuck at implementation of the ITreeNode).

**My question:**
How can I use functionalities of the TreeView such as "treeView1.Nodes.Add(topNode)" or "treeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Find(searchterm, True)" without actually having it on my form (I just need it to structure my data, without visualizing it).

I hope this makes sense and anyone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [`TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, there doesn't seem to be anything in it that is really tied to WinForms (it already seems to be inherited in a couple of other namespaces) so, assuming it gives you the functionality you need, can't you just use it?  e.g.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Sub Main
    Dim root = New TreeNode("Root")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node 1")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node 2")
    root.Nodes.Add("Node 3")
    root.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Node 1.1")
    root.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes.Add("Node 1.1.1")
    root.Nodes(1).Nodes.Add("Node 2.1")
    PrintNode(root, 0)
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Sub PrintNode(node As TreeNode, level As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", New String(" ", level * 2), node.Text)
    For Each child In node.Nodes
        PrintNode(child, level + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Root
  Node 1
    Node 1.1
      Node 1.1.1
  Node 2
    Node 2.1
  Node 3
```

Comment: This absolutely worked, Mark! Thank you for your detailed answer, and many apologies for my late response!